update user level according to the user ID
I have a problem when I want to change the data level, the problem is that the data level does not match the user ID
 public function updateLevel($level)
    {
        $checkuserToken = $this->users->where('level', $level)->first();
        if (count($checkuserToken) > 1) {
            if ($level == 'admin') {
                $data = [
                    'level' => 'superadmin',

                ];
                $activateUser = $this->users->update($checkuserToken, $data);
                if ($activateUser) {

                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                } else {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                }
                # code...
            } else {
                # code...
                $data = [
                    'level' => 'admin',

                ];
                $activateUser = $this->users->update($checkuserToken, $data);
                if ($activateUser) {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                } else {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                }
                # code...
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
        }

this is my controller
<?= $this->extend('admin/template') ?>

<?= $this->section('content') ?>

<main class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4 py-4">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/admin/admin">Admin</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Overview</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="h2">Admin</h1>

    <a href="<?= base_url('admin/addAdmin') ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-3 mb-2">Add Data</button></a>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gambar</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $no = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($admin as $r) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['nama'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['username'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['email'] ?></td>
                    <td><img src="<?= base_url('asset/upload/image/' . $r['image']) ?>" alt="" width="90" height="90" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= base_url('/admin/level/'  . $r['level']) ?>"><?php echo $r['level'] ?></a></td>
                    <td><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <footer class="pt-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>Copyright © 2019-2020 <a href="https://themesberg.com">Themesberg</a></span>
        <ul class="nav m-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary" aria-current="page" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="#">Terms and conditions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</main>
<?= $this->endSection() ?>

this is my views
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class AdminModel extends Model
{
    protected $table            = 'admin';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'id';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $returnType       = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes   = false;
    protected $protectFields    = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = ['nama', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'image', 'level', 'created_at'];

    protected bool $allowEmptyInserts = false;
    protected bool $updateOnlyChanged = true;

    protected array $casts = [];
    protected array $castHandlers = [];

    // Dates
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $dateFormat    = 'datetime';

    // Validation
    protected $validationRules      = [
        'nama' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|max_length[254]|is_unique[admin.username,id,{id}]',
        'email'    => 'required|max_length[254]|valid_email',
        'password' => 'required|max_length[255]|min_length[8]',
        'image' => 'uploaded[image]|mime_in[image,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png]|max_size[image,2048]'
    ];
    protected $validationMessages   = [];
    protected $skipValidation       = false;
    protected $cleanValidationRules = true;
}


this is my model
example
I want to change the data level with the user name tamaulanaa_
but that changes the data level with the user name udintod
what I expect is that if I change the data level it changes according to the user ID or username
what I expect is that if I change the data level it changes according to the user ID or username

You're not passing the user id to the updateLevel function in your view, so right now it is updating the first user it can find for the level you passed to it.
I'm not that familiar with CodeIgniter 4, but I'd reckon you'd need something like this:
Change $r['level'] to $r['id'] in the link in the view to pass along the user id instead of the level:
<td><a href="<?= base_url('/admin/level/'  . $r['id']) ?>"><?php echo $r['level'] ?></a></td>

And then use the user id in your controller method:
 public function updateLevel($id)
    {
        $checkuserToken = $this->users->where('id', $id)->first();
        if (count($checkuserToken) > 1) {
            if ($checkuserToken['level'] == 'admin') {
                $data = [
                    'level' => 'superadmin',

                ];
                $activateUser = $this->users->update($checkuserToken, $data);
                if ($activateUser) {

                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                } else {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                }
                # code...
            } else {
                # code...
                $data = [
                    'level' => 'admin',

                ];
                $activateUser = $this->users->update($checkuserToken, $data);
                if ($activateUser) {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                } else {
                    return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
                }
                # code...
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/admin/admin');
        }
    

Change the parameter of the function to $id, and change the first where to find the user by the given user id $id. When you then have the user, you can use $checkuserToken['level'] to get the user's current level.
